# How to convert string mm/DD/yy to timestamp format?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, timestamp

I am getting a date value from jQuery-Calender UI that is giving me the date in string format "mm/dd/yy" e.g 09/16/2012. Now I want to convert this into timestamp format "yyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss". Because in the database I have an attribute of Timestamp data type. How can I do this?

Using `$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" })`

I am accepting the input as `dateFrom = "2012-09-27"` but now I want to convert it into date format **yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss**

But I am getting the exception "unparsable Date ".

I am using following code:

```
java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");
java.util.Date test1=new java.util.Date (sdf.format(dateFrom));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using jquery's DatePicker UI tool then you can initialize a datepicker with the dateFormat option.

Initialize the datepicker's [dateFormat](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-dateFormat):

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
```

Or, set the dateFormat option, after init:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd" );
```

Note that this only provides a Date, not a Time.

Comment: Using $( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" }) now i am taking input as dateFrom = "2012-09-27" but now i want to convert into date format  "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" but i am getting exception "unparsable Date ". I am using following code:   java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");
java.util.Date test1=new java.util.Date (sdf.format(dateFrom));

Comment: Try appending `" 00:00:00"` to end of `dateFrom` in your java code, before you call `sdf.format`. Also, check your format string for SimpleDateFormat, it should be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified the language. But any language has DateTime method and it provides you options to change its format as you require.

I am answering for C#.

DateTime.Now.ToString("u"));

would output your required value.

For more help visit these links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format